# reproject layers in openlayers 3

Tags: postgresql, openlayers, postgis, openlayers-3, geoserver

I downloaded some data from OpenStreetMap and put them in PostGIS a couple of months ago. In all the tables that contain spatial data, the spatial column is `way geometry(Geometry,900913)` In Geoserver, `native SRS` is `EPSG:900913` so I guess the `EPSG` of the data is `900913`.

In my Openlayers 3.9.0 , the projection is left to default (`EPSG:3857`).

I want to create a tiled WMS layer of the PostGIS data.

By setting `params: {'CRS': 'EPSG:3857'},` in the layer , will this automatically reproject it from `900913` to `3857`, or I have to do some extra work?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The SRID 900913 was originally ["defined" *by OpenStreetMap*](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/EPSG:3857) for the projection Google Maps was using (replace G with 9, squint while looking at it, and let your mind wander over it). Later, EPSG added that SRS to their database but using code `EPSG:3857`. So they are identical.

I am not sure if OpenLayers is smart enough to do a *no-op* when data with `SRID=900913` needs to be displayed as `SRID=3857`. Just to make your life easier, update your `way` columns in PostGIS to use `SRID=3857`. You can use `ST_SetSRID()` for that.

Comment: But wait, in this case isnt the Openlayers responsible for front-end reprojection of the layer, and not the PostGIS? At least that's what I think the `CRS` does. I dont quite get it (oh I miss the old Openlayers). Thanks again